# how to design this UI in android app

Tags: android, user-interface

i am trying to create the following UI in android app[image]

In the above image all the five are to be image buttons. How to design this UI as like in the screen shot please help me friends....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `LinearLayout` take `RelativeLayout` and make it centrally aligned.Then

1. Take `first image` Near me and set it's property.
2. Now take the `second image` `Explore` and set it to `right` of `first image`.
3. Place `third image My network` and place it `below first image`.
4. `Fourth image Live` set this to `right of third image and and below second image`.
5. Now `center aligned` your `center image.`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 5 images, each of which has transparent areas. This layout type lets you position elements relative to the layout group itself, as well as to items within the group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Android advanced layout design, [but the common layout objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) give an idea:

There is a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) which gives you the ability to manipulate z-coördinates. In the SurfaceView you can then place a Grid/Relative/TableLayout for the 4 buttons (which you pre-render as rectangular images with transparency) and a simple Layout which centers and only contains the middle button.

If you then set the Z value of the first layout to less than that of the second you will get the view you want.

Comment: A SurfaceView to solve this problem is like using a wrecking ball to drive a nail.

Comment: @mah then is there a simple Android Layout that gives you z-axis control?

Comment: z-axis control isn't needed for this. RelativeLayout lets you have overlapping items, and the most recently added items to the layout group (lower in the xml, if defining that way) will be rendered  above the others. Even without that assist though, the image could easily be carved into more than 5 sections to avoid overlap. (9 ideally, to retain the best touchable area coverage).

Comment: nevertheless, say you wanted it because you e.g. want to place something dynamically over something else, what could you use then?